# Knockout binding not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, binding, knockout.js

I have developed a site with MVC4, jQuery and Twitter Boostrap. Now I decided to add knockout to some pages in order to make the workflow more fluent. On this particular page the intention  is to have a list of items to the left that can be reordered with jQuery UI sortable items. When clicked the details of each item will turn up in an area to the right for editing. Depending on type the the editing will be very different so I decided to have separate DIV tags that are made visible depending on type.

The previous working version loads the page items through the model. My idea was to add an observable array to the knockout viewmodel and then just load it on page load. The model is defined on the server so my intention was to not define all properties once again on the client viewmodel. Further manipulation and editing would just use the same collection and upload new/changed/deleted values to the server through AJAX calls.

I have read the knockout demos and searched stackoverflow for similar usecases. I think I followed the suggestions, but obviously something is missing. The model is loaded all right. The items turn up and are displayed with different colors depending on type. They are sortable and on resort the changes are sent back to server and persisted all right.

The missing part is the display and editing of the currently selected item. I added another property named currentItem to the viewmodel. In the function $("body").on("click", ".sortableItem" I can verify that the currentItem is loaded and the Heading property is correct.

But visibility and content of the DIV divEditType1 is not affected. Have I misunderstood the binding concept? Have I misunderstood the loading from server JSON array? Any help is most appreciated.

This is the server page model:

```
public class PresentationItemsModel
{
    public Guid PresentationId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public List<PresentationItemModel> PresentationItems { get; set; }
}
```

This is the repeated item model:

```
public class PresentationItemModel
{
    public Guid PresentationItemId { get; set; }
    public string PresentationItemType { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

This is the client page (irrelevant parts removed):

```
@model MyCustomWeb.Models.PresentationItemsModel

<header>
    <h2>@Model.DisplayName</h2>
</header>

<div style="float: left;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Current list</legend>
        <ul id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: presentationItems">
            <li class="sortableItem btn btn-block" data-bind="css: 'sortable' + PresentationItemType + 'Item'">
                <div style="font-weight: 500;">
                    <span data-bind="text: Heading"></span>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" style="display: inline-block; color: gray; float: right; opacity: 0.5; height: 14px; margin: 2px 4px 0 0"></span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="divEditType1" data-bind="visible: currentItem.PresentationItemType == 'Type1'" style="float: left; margin-left: 50px;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Type 1</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: currentItem.Heading" placeholder = "Enter Heading" />
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button id="btnDelete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="divEditType2" data-bind="visible: currentItem.PresentationItemType = 'Type2'" style="float: left; margin-left: 50px;">
</div>

<div id="divEditType3" data-bind="visible: currentItem.PresentationItemType = 'Type3'" style="float: left; margin-left: 50px;">
</div>


@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Enable item sorting
            $("#sortable").sortable(
                {
                    cursor: "move",
                    placeholder: "sortableSeparator",
                    update: function () {
                        // Create array of all changed items
                        var changeItems = [];
                        var currentOrderNumber = 1;
                        $(".sortableItem").each(function () {
                            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                            var previousOrderNumber = $(this).attr('data-orderNumber');
                            if (currentOrderNumber != previousOrderNumber)
                                changeItems.push({ "id": id, "orderNumber": currentOrderNumber });
                            currentOrderNumber += 1;
                        });
                        // Send ajax action
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "PUT",
                            url: "/api/PresentationApi/ChangeOrder/" + "@Model.PresentationId",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            data: JSON.stringify(changeItems)
                        });
                    },
                }
            );

            // Enable change depending on item click
            // Note: Must be done this way beacuse of the dynamic binding!
            $("body").on("click", ".sortableItem", function () {
                viewModel.currentItem = ko.dataFor(this);
                alert(viewModel.currentItem.Heading);  // Works fine!
                //alert(JSON.stringify(viewModel.currentItem));  // Also looks good!
            });



            // Knockout view model
            function ViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.presentationItems = ko.observableArray([]);
                self.currentItem = ko.observable();
            }

            var viewModel = new ViewModel();
            viewModel.presentationItems(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PresentationItems)));
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Edit:
An attempt to create a Fiddle demo can be found here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/XXNz9/

Comment: Can you post the resulting json of @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PresentationItems)) ? And can you make a fiddle that reproduces the probem ?

Comment: I am not used to fiddle, but I tried to reproduce the case in an example. That same example creates a list when executed in my VS2012 context, but in fiddle I don't even get that ...

http://jsfiddle.net/XXNz9/

Maybe you can find some obvious mistake?

Comment: jsFiddle seems to be a useful tool which is meaningful to learn. But I am confused. There is a dropdownbox where I can choose to add Knockout or jQuery to the example. Does that mean I can not have both?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to wrap your "divEditType1" with another div. The context of inner div will change to "currentItem" so you you won't need to write it every time

```
<div data-bind="with: currentItem">
    <div id="divEditType1" data-bind="visible: PresentationItemType = 'Type1'" style="float: left; margin-left: 50px;">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit Type 1</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Heading" placeholder = "Enter Heading" />
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button id="btnDelete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</div>
```

This can also solve your problem because your binding can fail if currentItem == null when applied

Comment: Thanks. Good practise, but it made no difference in my example.

Comment: @JakobLithner You are setting **selectedItem** with the wrong way. You need to set an observable value `viewModel.currentItem(ko.dataFor(this));` instead of usual assignment

Comment: Thanks!!! It was that simple ... What fooled me was my alert checking of the set value which was actually correct. I guess I destroyed the observable variant and made it static by setting it the wrong way? Do you have any suggestions on how to debug knockout code?

Comment: Yes, you've assigned another object to the property. And it wouldn't also work if you'd assign another observable.
There is a Chrome plugin for knockout debugging http://goo.gl/WXEyyz. But I'm almost not using it, just using console for it. And also using typescript - it helps to avoid such a simple mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, I will give the Chrome knockout plugin a try!